# oracle apex passing a variable into another form by reference

Tags: oracle-apex

I try to launch a page with a value that I dervived from another page
e.g. 
I launch a page like so

```
http://fred:5000/pls/apex/f?p=124:5:2632147971760575604::NO:5:P5_SAMACCOUTNAME:P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME
```

P5_SAMACCOUTNAME is an item name of a text box from page5
and 
P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME is an item name of a text box from page4

How I can de-referenced that item by name and get the actually value ?
and pass it on to a URL ??

Comment: How are you constructing the URL?  Normally, wherever you are creating a link will give you a wizard to specify what items to set on the target page based on items on the current page.

Comment: You're missing the &. notation, in urls to reference the value of an item you should enclose it like this: &P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME. (notice the dot at the end)

Comment: in page 4 make a link to page 5, and set the P5_SAMACCOUTNAME with the value of P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME, APEX parse the value in the link

Answer (score 0):

Kayama,

> I try to launch a page with a value that I dervived from another page e.g. I launch a page like so
>   P5_SAMACCOUTNAME is an item name of a text box from page5 and P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME is an item name of a text box from page4

means you want to pass value of P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME to P5_SAMACCOUNTNAME
so simple pass as follows :

```
http://fred:5000/pls/apex/f?p=124:5:2632147971760575604::NO:5:P5_SAMACCOUTNAME:&P4_SAMACCOUNTNAME.
```

hope this helps.